# Can a map be used in the 'def __init__' ? And how to read errors

Tags: oop, python-3.x, dictionary

I've created a class for a Counter that I'm wanting to build, and I want this object to figure out player scores. I'm expecting to see 3 when I test it, however what I get is the following error: 
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for += 'method' and 'int'` I'm not sure what that means, so I'm not sure if the issue is the map, my object itself, or my syntax. Any and all advice is welcome!

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pointValue = {'Item_1': 3,
                           'Item_2': 5,
                           'Item_3': -3
        }

    def playerScore(self, itemFound ):
        self.playerScore += (self.pointValue[itemFound])
        return self.playerScore

gameCounter = Counter()

x = 'Item_1'
print (gameCounter.playerScore(x))
```

Comment: why are you adding a method?

Comment: Why are you trying to add to a method? Presumably there should be a "score" attribute and a "find item" method (see [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) on naming).

Comment: I'm very new to this, so I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing. My thought was, "If the counter is the thing, then it should have a function to find score. Is a method and function the same thing?

Comment: It's fine to have a method (like a function, but bound to a class/instance) to find the score, but your method tries to add to itself (what would that even mean?) and then return itself. It's probably worth looking through https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely use a map (in Python it's called a `dict`) in `__init__`; it is not that part of the code that is throwing the error.

The message `unsupported operand type(s) for += 'method' and 'int'` refers to the line

```
self.playerScore += (self.pointValue[itemFound])
```

where `self.playerScore` is the *method you are currently calling*; it makes no sense to add an integer to a method, so an error is raised.

I think you actually want something like:

```
class ScoreCounter:

    POINT_VALUE = {'Item_1': 3,
                   'Item_2': 5,
                   'Item_3': -3}

    def __init__(self):
        self.score = 0

    def find_item(self, item):
        self.score += self.POINT_VALUE.get(item, 0)
        return self.score
```

Which you could use like:

```
>>> c = ScoreCounter()
>>> c.find_item("Item_1")
3
```

Note that the `POINT_VALUE` is a class attribute, shared by all `ScoreCounter` instances, whereas the `score` is an instance attribute, separate for each one. Also note that `score` is a different name to `find_item`, so you don't end up trying to assign to the method, and I have avoided the name `Counter` as it's [used elsewhere](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Finally, I have adopted naming conventions from [the Python style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: "where self.playerScore is the method you are currently calling; it makes no sense to add an integer to a method, so an error is raised."

That makes so much sense! Thank you. Also why do attributes not use self. ?

Comment: @Aka_Minimal what do you mean? The attribute access within the class *does* use `self`.

Comment: Well I notice that with score you add the self, but you don't write
self.POINT_VALUE.

Comment: @Aka_Minimal inside the methods I do - `self.POINT_VALUE.get(item, 0)`. Outside the methods but inside the class definition you don't (and can't, `self` isn't defined) use `self` - it's not `def self.__init__` either!